# How can i avoid or fix time outs in Selenium Java?

Tags: selenium, java

I'am using `Selenium with Standalone Server (V2.48.2)` with `NetBeans` and using `Firefox (V44.0)`.

I have tried different ways to get this fixed, but its an error that appears to be random in different parts of my code every once in a while; **"Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for presence of element located"** Sometimes it works all fine and processes everything.

I currently use `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(by))` method to wait for page to load, but it is still giving me this issue.
This occurs in a filter of 4 dropdown lists, one enables another:

```
<form name="ymme-form">
          <select name="year" id="year">
                  <option>Year</option></select>
          <select name="make" disabled="">
                  <option>Make</option></select>
          <select name="model" disabled="">
                  <option>Model</option></select>
          <select name="engine" disabled="">
                  <option>Engine</option></select>
     <button class="button" disabled="">
                 <span>ADD VEHICLE</span></button></form>
```

The next code is highly modified from what i had in the beginning (note the Try Catch code repeated) because i tried to force this in many ways, but any advice on the code is highly appreciated:

```
for(int attemptMake = 0; attemptMake<attemptsForFilters;attemptMake++){
                           try{
                            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("make")));
                           boolean makeDisplay = driver.findElement(By.name("make")).isDisplayed();
                           boolean makeFilters = driver.findElement(By.name("make")).isEnabled();
                             if(makeDisplay){
                                   if(makeFilters){
                                    Select makeSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("make")));
                                      List<WebElement> listMake = makeSelect.getOptions();
                                           for(int m = 1;m<listMake.size();m++){
                                               if(listMake.get(m).getText().toLowerCase().equals(lineProcess.make.toLowerCase())){
                                                          makeProcess = listMake.get(m).getText();
                                                          makeSelect.selectByIndex(m);
                                                          break;
                                               }
                                           }
                                      }
                                                 } else if (!makeFilters){
                                                    System.out.println("Not Make Option detected for: " + lineProcess.model + " - attempt: " + attemptMake);
                                                }
                           } catch(Exception e){
                                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("make")));
                           boolean makeDisplay = driver.findElement(By.name("make")).isDisplayed();
                           boolean makeFilters = driver.findElement(By.name("make")).isEnabled();
                             if(makeDisplay){
                                   if(makeFilters){
                                    Select makeSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("make")));
                                      List<WebElement> listMake = makeSelect.getOptions();
                                           for(int m = 1;m<listMake.size();m++){
                                               if(listMake.get(m).getText().toLowerCase().equals(lineProcess.make.toLowerCase())){
                                                          makeProcess = listMake.get(m).getText();
                                                          makeSelect.selectByIndex(m);
                                                          break;
                                               }
                                           }
                                      }
                                                 } else if (!makeFilters){
                                                    System.out.println("Not Make Option detected for: " + lineProcess.model + " - attempt: " + attemptMake);
                                                }
                           }
                           }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Edit:**

Also I'm constantly getting this error

> **Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no
>   longer attached to the DOM**

Even if I have waited for the Element before or validated it:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='ymmeOverlayMainContent']/div[@class='ymmeWidget']/form/button[@class='button']")));
                            WebElement submitAddvehicle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ymmeOverlayMainContent']/div[@class='ymmeWidget']/form/button[@class='button']"));
                            if(submitAddvehicle.isEnabled()){
                                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ymmeOverlayMainContent']/div[@class='ymmeWidget']/form")).click();
                                submitAddvehicle.click();
                                executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", submitAddvehicle); //<---- Here is the error
                                executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", submitAddvehicle);
                                }
```

Comment: if i get this error in katalon recoreder how can i resolve this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing some heavy research, I was able to find the solution by using:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.finder));
```

The key was to find all the elements present in the part where i was going to validate if it was available. This solved the Time out's error:

As for the Element is no longer attached to the DOM, and the validations,
instead of using the .IsDisplayed or .IsEnabled which DON'T returns "false" but an exception, i was able to validate this using

`findElements(By.finder).size()>0`

This returns false or true if the element size is displaying or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities what is going on:

1. some call of selenium functions will time out (click, type, etc.) after some time because the object is not there at all.
2. even if you will enable the wait.until, this has its own timeout (could be 30 sec.) in selenium.

Case 1) is solved by enabling waits before some click or other action should happen.

To solve case 2) for extremely slow applications you have to check presence of some object in the cycle and continue afterwards.

Try to use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903231/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present to get you test waiting for your app.

Answer (score 0):

use implicit wait to handle all kind of sync issues.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

user this at the time of declaring the web driver object;
like:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
WebElement myDynamicElement = driver.findElement(By.id("myDynamicElement"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are facing an issue when you are loosing an element attached to the DOM because JavaScript has been triggered once you do selection from dropdown.
The solution will be next:

```
1. Select Year from dropdown (usually that will trigger JavaScript execution)
2. Wait for unique element to be present/displayed/selected (this element should not be displayed before step 1 and should appear only after step 1 execution, e.g. wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected(By.xpath(<xpath for selected option>)));)
3. Select Make (that will trigger JavaScript execution again)
4. Wait for unique element to be present/displayed (this element should not be displayed before step 2 and should appear only after step 2)
```

and so on with every next selection

This will resolve both issues

p.s. If you are using implicit waits on browser set up, run driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS); before initiating explicit wait.